# How do I find out which iOS hardware devices are associated with the devices in Apple's AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType API?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

I'm looking at Apple's `AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType` API. But in the documentation Apple doesn't specifically talk about which released hardware has which camera system.

For example, I know `.builtInTripleCamera` is used by **iPhone 14 Pro** (it has three cameras and I am using it personally to debug my apps), but what *other* hardware devices use `.builtInTripleCamera`? **Is there a list somewhere?**

And what about `.builtInDualWideCamera` and all the others listed on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype as well?

Or am I left to try and figure this out myself?

**Why I want to know this....**

I'm trying to determine the proper order of a `DeviceType` array for a `DiscoverySession` based on historical device release order. I want my `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to use what Apple would show as default on their own Camera app, and Apple is unclear of what that actually is.

For example, in this code:

```
let deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType]
deviceTypes = [.builtInTripleCamera, .builtInDualWideCamera, .builtInDualCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera]

let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
    deviceTypes: deviceTypes,
    mediaType: .video,
    position: .back
)
```

What order should I put `deviceTypes` in to match what Apple uses for their own default Camera app? Does `.builtInDualWideCamera` come before `.builtInDualCamera`? Should I include `.builtInUltraWideCamera` in the list, and was there a device that has just this type of camera? How would I know?

Comment: Why do you need to know this at all? Just look to see what the current device has and act accordingly; there's no merit in distinguishing by model. It's just like screen sizes; you don't keep a list of devices and screen sizes, you look to see how big _this_ device's screen is.

Comment: @matt Because I'm trying to determine the proper order of a `AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType` array for a `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession` based on their release. I want my `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to use what Apple would show as default on their Camera app, and Apple is unclear of what that actually is.

Comment: Updated my question to be more clear.